# Nodejs controller not working properly

Tags: node.js

```
router.get('/roomlist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('roomlist');
    collection.find(function(e,docs){
        res.render('roomlist', {
            "roomlist" : docs
        });
    });
});
```

The above controller is used to get list of rooms under a table "ROOMLIST". I need to get the details. I need to display all the roomname in the table ROOMLIST.

Comment: how is it not working? What is it doing? What are you expecting it to do? What errors is it raising?

Comment: Failed to lookup view "roomname" in views directory

Comment: I added 2 braces {} before that function code and it throws the latest error ..

Comment: h1 RoomList
                select
                    each room, i in roomlist
                        option
                                    =room.roomname     <---This is my view .

Comment: If any answer has provided solution to your problem, you should accept it and close the question. If you've found the solution yourself, you should post it here and accept it as solution thereby closing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use find method of mongodb to get the documents from a collection. And then use cursor to iterate through the documents.

```
var getRoomlist = function(db, callback) {
   var cursor =db.collection('roomlist').find( );
   cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
      assert.equal(err, null);
      if (doc != null) {
         return callback(false, doc);
      } else {
         return callback(true, null);
      }
   });
};
```

Then you can use your route `/roomlist`, to call the function getRoomlist when it gets hit and render the doc.

```
router.get('/roomlist', function(req, res){
  programLogic(function(err, doc){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    return res.send(doc);
  });
});
```

If you still don't get it, just clone this and run through it

```
var programLogic = function (cb){
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    getRoomlist(db, function(err, doc) {
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
      return cb(false, doc);
    });
  });
}// programLogic ends

var getRoomlist = function(db, callback) {
   var cursor =db.collection('roomlist').find( );
   cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
      assert.equal(err, null);
      if (doc != null) {
         return callback(false, doc);
      } else {
         return callback(true, null);
      }
   });
};

router.get('/roomlist', function(req, res){
  programLogic(function(err, doc){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    return res.send(doc);
  });
});
```

Comment: router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('usercollection');
    collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('userlist', {
            "userlist" : docs
        });
    });
});    <--- this one is also using the same database. Only tables vary. this one is working properly . why not the other thing???

Answer (score 0):

Which engine do you use for views rendering? Based on error message, property "roomname" has been interpreted as a partial, and cannot be found in views directory.

Comment: I am using express templating

Comment: @sriramraghunathan have you set everything correctly? are you use jade, swig or maybe handlebars? http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: yes everything is perfect .I am sure because i am using the same to get the userlist which is working perfectly.

Comment: The only difference between working example (users), and not working example (rooms), is: for room you pass only callback as a parameter for find method; for users you pass empty query {}, empty options {}, and then, as last argument the callback.

Comment: I did that and it is not working. any other suggestion @grom??